# Getting C++ function mangled name

Tags: c++, clang, code-coverage

I am trying to track code coverage for C++ and I would like to specify what functions a particular test covers. I would like to have a macro or template that gives me the mangled name of the function so in the test I can specify which methods are covered and I can match this up with the mangled names in the coverage information generated. I've been fiddling for some time but have been unable to get this to work. Prefer it worked with overloaded methods too

```
COVERS_BEGIN_FUNCTIONS
  COVERS_CLASS_FUNCTION( atestfile::aFunction( int ) );
COVERS_END_FUNCTIONS
```

Comment: Normally you don't mangle names, you [demangle](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html) them.

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. Why can't you declare `extern T0 my_func(T1, T2, T3, ...);` and call `my_func` in your code? You will still have to write code to pass variables of type T1, T2, T3, and receive + check that T0 is the correct value, right?

Comment: Reading the question again, it sounds more like you need `c++filt`, which translates mangled names to demangled ones?

Comment: @nwp Im not trying to mangle them Im trying to attach info to each test case saying what functions its covering and use that to filter the returned coverage information

Comment: Why don't you use existing code coverage tools?

Comment: @vtt Can you suggest something that does per test coverage?

Comment: It should be possible with gcov: run a single test, obtain coverage.

Comment: @vtt thats basically what I am doing but with clang. I am trying to filter the returned coverage though so it only counts code as covered if that test specifies that it covers that code. basically trying to do the equivalent of PHPUnit Covers annotation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will answer your question directly but these resources might be of assistance:

- [DUMPBIN utility mangled name output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759324/dumpbin-utility-mangled-name-output)
- [printing the c++ name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818651/printing-the-c-name-mangling)
- http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is what I finally came up with that seems to work (at least for clang)

```
namespace testing {
    namespace coverage {
    inline std::string toString( const std::list<std::string> &list ) {
      std::ostringstream out;
      bool first = true;
      for ( const auto &item : list ) {
        if ( first ) {
          first = false;
        } else {
          out << std::endl;
        }
        out << item;
      }
      return out.str();
    }

    template<typename T> struct returnExtract { typedef void type; };
    template<typename R, typename...A> struct returnExtract<R( A... )> { typedef R type; };
    template<typename...> struct argsExtract { static std::string toString() { return std::string(); } };
    template<typename T, typename Y, typename... A> struct argsExtract<T, Y, A...> {
      static std::string toString() {
        return boost::core::demangled_name( typeid( T ) ) + ", " + argsExtract<Y, A...>::toString();
      }
    };
    template<typename T> struct argsExtract<T> { static std::string toString() { return boost::core::demangled_name( typeid( T ) ); } };
    template<typename T, typename... A> struct argsExtract<T( A... )> { static std::string toString() { return argsExtract<A...>::toString(); } };
    template<typename T> struct argsExtract<T()> { static std::string toString() { return std::string(); } };

    std::string functionComponentsToString( const std::type_info &returnType, const std::type_info &classType, const char *functionName,
                                            const std::string &argumentTypes, const std::string &templateArguments = std::string() ) {
      std::ostringstream rt;
      if ( not templateArguments.empty() ) {
        rt << boost::core::demangled_name( returnType ) << " ";
      }
      rt << boost::core::demangled_name( classType ) << "::" << functionName;
      if ( not templateArguments.empty() ) {
        rt << "<" << templateArguments << ">";
      }
      rt << "(" << argumentTypes << ")";
      return rt.str();
    }

    template<typename... X> struct functionCheck {};
    template<typename A, typename B, typename... C> struct functionCheck<A, B( C... )> { inline static void func( B (A::*)( C... ) ) {} };
  }
}

#define COVERS_BEGIN_FUNCTIONS { \
  std::list<std::string> functions;
#define COVERS_CLASS_FUNCTION( c, n, s ) \
  functions.emplace_back( testing::coverage::functionComponentsToString( typeid( testing::coverage::returnExtract<s>::type ), typeid( c ), #n, testing::coverage::argsExtract<s>::toString() ) ); \
  testing::coverage::functionCheck<c,s>::func( &c::n );
#define COVERS_CLASS_FUNCTION_T( c, n, s, t... ) \
  functions.emplace_back( testing::coverage::functionComponentsToString( typeid( testing::coverage::returnExtract<s>::type ), typeid( c ), #n, testing::coverage::argsExtract<s>::toString(), testing::coverage::argsExtract<t>::toString() ) ); \
  testing::coverage::functionCheck<c,s>::func( &c::n<t> );
#define COVERS_END_FUNCTIONS RecordProperty("COVERS_FUNCTIONS", testing::coverage::toString(functions) ); \
}
```

This allows me to put

```
  COVERS_BEGIN_FUNCTIONS
    COVERS_CLASS_FUNCTION( atestfile, aFunction, int( const char *) );
    COVERS_CLASS_FUNCTION_T( atestfile, aTestFunction, void( int ), int );
    COVERS_CLASS_FUNCTION_T( atestfile, aTestFunction, void( const char* ), const char* );
  COVERS_END_FUNCTIONS
```

In the test case which calls RecordProperty with a newline separated string of function signatures that I can compare to the mangled names in the coverage data (unmangling them first)